# Modifying a collection in AngularJS based on random input array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Is there anyway to build a collection of the type:

```
var demoObject = 
{
  param1: value1,
  param2: value2,
  param3: value3,
  ...
}
```

where both param and value are from an input array, and can extend to 'n' number of values i.e the demo object should be dynamic.

Problem: I am comparing two arrays and hoping to populate above collection based on certain criteria. Both the paramX and valueX are obtained from either of the arrays easily.

I have tried: Splicing and generating my own array, building custom objects using angular.forEach ... but none of the outputs give me a result in the above format of "var demoObject". 
The API I am feeding this object requires a fixed JSON format, and I intend to to do angular.ToJson(demoObject)
Appreciate any inputs, thoughts.

Comment: What do the input arrays look like?

Comment: And what are your comparison criteria ?

Comment: The input arrays are something like array[0] = Attribute1: Value1, Attribute2: Value2, ... array[1] = Attribute1: Value1, Attribute2: Value2 ... The comparison criteria would be if array1[i].Value != array2[i].Value or on similar lines

Comment: To be honest, the criteria is not an issue, i just need to know if there is someway i can populate the entire demoObject using values only from some array, or is the LHS of the assignment always hardcoded (In which case I would build massive IF statements ><)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
var demoObject = {};
var someArray = [
    {useIt: true, paramName: 'jane', value: 'hi there'},
    {useIt: false, paramName: 'tom', value: 'bonjour'},
    {useIt: true, paramName: 'mary', value: 'hola'}
];

var paramNum = 1;
for (var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
    if (someArray[i].useIt) {
        demoObject[someArray[i].paramNname] = someArray[i].value;
    }
}

console.log(demoObject);
// Object {jane: "hi there", mary: "hola"}    

console.log(demoObject.jane);
// hi there
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I think i was too hung up on angular.forEach that I failed to use a simple for loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand what you are trying to archive since I might not correctly understand your question.

But when it comes to demo data I use faker.js (https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/). This is a Javascript node module which allows you to generate all sorts of demo data. Which can be very useful. 
Check it out you will like it ... 
HTH

Comment: I am just looking to build a dynamic object of the format in my Question, which populates all data from some array. Thank you for faker.js, will surely check it out for my testing.